# Wanted to duplicate a rigify rig to slightly modify it and add it to another character but now it won´t generate a rig

Tags: rigging, rigify

I had a character which I rigged with Rigify (did some alterations to the standard Rigify rig), and wanted to duplicate it (<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>), and change the arm position for a character of equal build that had a different idle pose (The first one wasn't a t-pose which was a big oopsies from my part).

Unfortunately, when I try to generate the rig the button states "Re-generate rig" even though I hadn't generated a rig with the duplicated rig, and it doesn't allow me to generate the control rig, I get the error `Target Rig Not Visible`. Anyone knows how to fix this?

And what's the best way forward of duplicated previously used Rigify rigs?

Comment: "it doesn´t allow me to generate the control rig" could you clarify this? Do you have an error message or anything ?

Comment: it says "Target Rig Not Visible"

Comment: Which Blender version do you use? In older Blender versions the generated rig must be visible when you want to re-create it. Otherwise you get an error. Is the "rig" visible? A screenshot would help ;-) Maybe the duplicated metarig uses the same settings for some reason. Have you checked the *Advanced* settings below the *(Re-)Generate Rig* button? The target rig and UI script settings should be unique.

Answer (score 0):

When you generate a rig with Rigify, it can either create new assets or update existing ones.

By default, when you generate for the first time in a blender scene, it will create a new rig, Rig UI script and Widgets. After that first generation, any time your hit the generate button, it updates the existing assets.

When you duplicate a metarig and want to create a new rig, you have to tell Rigify to do so. Otherwise, it will keep updating the other rig.
Here you get the error `Target Rig Not Visible` because you moved the previous rig into a disabled collection, hence it can't access it and throws the error.

If you select the new metarig and look into Properties Editor > Armature Data tab > Rigify Panel > Advanced Sub-Panel:

[image]

You can see here that the new metarig is still set up to overwrite the old rig.

Click the <kbd>X</kbd> icons at the end of the names of the *Target Rig*, *Rig UI script* and *Widgets Collection* (though that one can be left as is if you just create regular rigs with the same widgets, to save memory).
You can even give your future rig a name.

[image]

Notice as well that, when you have no target rig, the button change from "Re-Generate Rig" to "Generate Rig". You can click it, and it will create a new rig.

[image]